# Average distance (maximum norm) from origin to the nearer of two random points in a unit square

Tags: probability, geometry, average

I got a unit square, the origin (0,0) and two random points which are uniformly distributed on the 1x1 unit square. 
What is the **average distance in maximum norm** from origin to the nearer of the two random points?

So for example we've got (0,0) and (0.4,0.3) and (0.2,0,9) as random points => distance to origin in maximum norm is 0.4 and 0.9 => so the minimum would be 0.4.

I already know that the average distance between origin and ONE random point in a unit square is 2/3 (maximum norm)...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For two independent random variables $X, Y$ you can calculate the CDF of $\min(X, Y)$ and $\max(X, Y)$ via the formulae

$$ P(\max(X, Y) \le x) = P(X \le x \wedge Y \le x) = P(X \le x) P(Y \le x)$$
$$P(\min(X, Y) \le x) = 1 - P(\min(X, Y) > x) = 1 - P(X > x \wedge Y > x)\\
= 1 - P(X > x) P(Y > x) = 1 - (1 - P(X \le x))(1 - P(Y \le x))$$

Now apply this to determine the CDF of $\min(\max(X_1, X_2), \max(X_3, X_4))$, where the $X_i$ are i.i.d uniformly on $[0, 1]$ distributed. From the CDF you can then calculate the mean via the well-known formulae.